# How to make an absolute element take up as much width as it requires in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS dropdown menu. The wrapper class (`.dropdown`) needs to be inline-block, because you would want to stack more than one horizontally. However, this makes it so that the menu (`.menu`) only takes up a maximum of the width the `.dropdown` class. Some like this:

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown .menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
}
.dropdown .menu.right {
    right: 0;
}
.dropdown .menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .menu ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .menu ul > li.content {
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
}
.dropdown .menu ul > li.divider {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.dropdown .menu ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown .menu ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}
.dropdown .trigger.hover + .menu:hover,
.dropdown .trigger.hover:hover + .menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown button.trigger + .menu:active,
.dropdown button.trigger:focus + .menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="trigger hover">Pick your fruit from a list <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="content">
                        Fruits
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mangoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pineapples (on a Pizza)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Peaches</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see, the pineapples choice on the list could take up more space, but it doesn't and instead goes to a new line because of its parent element. How can I make it so that all the children elements of the dropdown menu takes up as much width as they need?

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` ?

Comment: the duplicate is a generic one explaining the behavior of position:absolute and the end will understand why the above fixes your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just add `whitespace: nowrap;` for `.dropdown .menu ul > li`.**